# Laravel Transaction: How to do commit some queries instead of rollback all?

Tags: mysql, laravel, transactions

The transaction block on exception aborting the request, so that rollback. But now whenever exception arise, need to store the data - the exception details to a table. When aborting the request the insert/update query also get rollback.

```php
\DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
    try{
        // operations
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $exception_model = new ExceptionModel();
        $exception_model->user = $request->user_info;
        $exception_model->detail = $e;
        $exception_model->save();

        abort(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, 'Something went wrong');
    }
});
```

But since it's automatically rolling back (ie., laravel transaction closure), the exception model changes also rollback. How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the transaction inside the try block should work:

```
use Exception;

try {
    \DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
        // operations
    });
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $exception_model = new ExceptionModel();
    $exception_model->user = $request->user_info;
    $exception_model->detail = $e;
    $exception_model->save();

    abort(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, 'Something went wrong');
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried with the case, Seems not woking as expected.

Comment: Just tested it and it works for me, what is not working for you?

Comment: I tried with the below snippet
```php 
try{ 
    \DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
        try{
            //operation
        }catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    });
}catch(Exception $e){ 
    .....
    $exception_model->save();
    abort(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, 'Something went wrong');
}```

Comment: I don't see a reason to use another try catch inside the transaction, have you imported the correct exception class? e.g. `use Exception;`

Comment: The block you mentioned in the answer working as expected. ie without try and catch inside the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You could manually use transactions, outside of closures. That way you will be able to store data in your `$exception_model`:

```
    try{
        DB::beginTransaction(); //Initiate transaction
        // operations
        DB::commit(); //Commit transaction after all the operations
    }catch(Exception $e){
        DB::rollBack(); //Rollback if the exception occurs, but still save data  in your exception model
        $exception_model = new ExceptionModel();
        $exception_model->user = $request->user_info;
        $exception_model->detail = $e;
        $exception_model->save();

        abort(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, 'Something went wrong');
    }
```

Read more on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions), on segment *Manually Using Transactions*

Comment: Is there any other way in Transaction Closure method itself to do it?

Comment: Judging by the documentation, the `Transaction closure` itself doesn't handle exceptions. One solution I have in my head is to save all the exception variables inside the `catch` block, and initiate `ExceptionModel` after the `Transaction closure` to save them. That might do the trick